# Inactive session in multiple tabs open

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I dealing with one problem. I have user idle timer built in jQuery so that if user is not active for 30 minutes he's been logged out of the app. This works perfectly on one browser tab open. Now I would like to have the same thing just for multiple tabs. So, if user open few tabs and work in only one of them he's still active for all app, my current set up logs him out from other tabs which he didn't use for 30 minutes. How can I communicate with all tabs at the same time? Thanks in advance, Wolf.

Comment: AJAX? A DB? Please share the code that you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

- create a common timer for all the pages.A single function would do.Place this function in a separate js file
- start your timer on window.onload.Pause your timer on [window.blur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_blur.asp).Restart your timer on [window.focus](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_focus.asp)

  -include this on every page of your application.

  You can get much more help if you show your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I'm looking for. For me the user is active when he's doing something not just to have my app tab open. So, my function currently check this events (mousemove keydown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel mousedown touchstart touchmove), but if the user move a mouse in other tab how can I know that so I can restart my timer? Sorry if I wasn't clear in my post.

Comment: you are getting it completely wrong...you will need window.blur and focus to know when the user switches to tabs...there is no other way to recon it...